# Dependency Injection in Angular compared to .Net Dependency Injection

Tags: .net, angular, dependency-injection

I'm from .NET background, just a question on Dependency Injection in Angular.

In .NET/.NET Core, there are three different service lifetimes which are: Transient, Scoped and Singleton. But for Angular, it only has equivalent "Singleton", is my understanding correct? If yes, why Angular not provide other service type like "Transient"?

Answer (score 4):

Technically, all services in Angular are `scoped`. However, they can be scoped to:

1. Root - an instance of a service provided in the root (or injected in AppModule) is shared between all modules and components. This is also what we call a **singleton**, scoped to root (entire app).

> ```
> @Injectable({
>   providedIn: 'root',
> })
> ```

2. Module - an instance of a service provided in a lazy-loaded module is shared between the components of the module. This is also a **singleton**, but scoped to a module.

> ```
> @NgModule({
>   ...
>   providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }]
> })
> ```

3. Component - an instance of a service injected into a component only lives while that component lives. Once that component is destroyed, the instance o the service is also destroyed. Multiple instances of the same component each have their own instance of the service.

> ```
> @Component({
>   ...
>   providers: [{ provide: ItemService, useValue: { name: 'lamp' } }]
> })
> ```

This section of the documentation touches upon the hierarchy of injection: https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection